# 関数の戻り値を受けた変数が型推論されない

Tags: typescript

以下のコードで、関数の戻り値が `Promise<Foo>` なので `await` した `foo` の型は `Foo` になると思ったのですが `any` になってエラーが出ます。なぜですか。

コード

```
type Foo = {
  bar: string | undefined;
};

const getFooPromise = async (prevBar?: string | undefined): Promise<Foo> => {
  const responce = await fetch("https://example.com/foo?bar=" + prevBar);
  return responce.json();
};

const getBarPromise = async (): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  let bar: string | undefined = undefined;

  do {
    const foo = await getFooPromise(bar); // ←ここ
    bar = foo.bar;
  } while (bar);

  return bar;
};
```

エラー

```
error TS7022: 'foo' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

Comment: こちらのissueと同事象かなと思います(原因などについては書かれていないようです): https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36687

Comment: `noImplicitAny` と `strictNullChecks` が有効だとエラーになるようですね。